# Make tkinter widgets expand to fill up horizontal space

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code that generates a GUI window with `tkinter`:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._create_widgets()        

    def _create_widgets(self):
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=4)

        text_1_label = ttk.Button(self, text="Browse text file 1 ...")
        text_1_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

        text_1_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        text_1_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.EW, padx=5, pady=5)

        text_2_label = ttk.Button(self, text="Browse text file 2 ...")
        text_2_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

        text_2_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        text_2_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.EW, padx=5, pady=5)

        lf = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Thresholds")
        lf.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.EW, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        treshold_1_label = ttk.Label(lf, text="Accelerations")
        treshold_1_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

        treshold_1_entry = ttk.Entry(lf)
        treshold_1_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.EW, padx=5, pady=5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.geometry("400x400") 
    app.mainloop()
```

which when run generates the following:

[image: tkinter window]

However I would like all Entry widgets to automatically expand to fill up all available horizontal space. At first I thought that the `sticky=tk.EW` parameter would accomplish this, but apparently this is not the case.

Would anyone here be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you really mean to configure the weight of column 0 twice, but column 1 not at all?

Comment: @jasonharper No, this was a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my post.

Comment: You would need to set weights on `lf` as well, if you want its columns to be over the minimum width needed to hold their contents.

Answer (score 1):

When using `grid`, a good rule of thumb is to always give a non-zero weight to at least one row and one column. This instructs `grid` how to allocate extra space that might be in a parent.

In your case, you haven't done that in your label frame even though you're using `grid` to manage its children.

The simple solution is to give a weight of 1 to column 1, which will cause that column to grow when the label frame grows.

```
lf.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

[image: screenshot]